# Unable to ssh into Cent OS container from windows host. Same is working with linux host

Tags: docker

I am creating a jenkins slave node and for that I am using following SSHD enabled cent OS image **stefanlehmann/centos-jenkins-docker-slave**.
On windows host I am unable to ssh into the container. Same is working with linux host.

Docker is installed on windows and switched to linux container from docker settings.
I have enabled the remote API by going through **docker settings** > **general** > **Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without tls**.

After exposing the daemon, jenkins can access docker host.
Now, I want docker container should be accessible from jenkins.  Container has SSHD enabled and running.

I started the container using following command to enable the sshd service

**docker run --tmpfs /run -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro --name test2 -d stefanlehmann/centos-jenkins-docker-slave /sbin/init)**

**ssh jenkins@container_ip** should be working in windows also. Its working fine in linux.

---

**NOTE:** in linux to enable remote API I made following changes
Open **docker.service** file **“/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service file”**

Search for ExecStart and replace the value
**ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd** to **ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock**
**sudo service docker restart**

---

Comment: You don’t need an ssh daemon, then: anyone who has network access to the host can `DOCKER_HOST=tcp://your.ip:4243 docker run -v /:/host -it busybox sh` and make arbitrary changes to the host filesystem with root-level permissions.  ...actually this is a massive security issue, and you should turn off the `-H tcp://0.0.0.0` option _now_, and consider reinstalling the system.

Comment: Usually you don’t have ssh access into containers and you definitely don’t have remote Docker API access (because it’s so difficult to secure).  Can you describe the higher-level problem you’re trying to solve where you’d need either of these?

Comment: I want to set up a Jenkins slave node using Docker. So, actually, there would be a master node on one host machine and multiple slave nodes (docker containers) on a different host. While setting up this configuration in Jenkins master should be able to access the slave node (docker container) via ssh. I am currently testing it on a windows machine but not able to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Every tutorial has suggested this approach. One such tutorial is this https://rafaelnexus.com/tutorials/jenkins-master-and-slaves-as-docker-containers/